# How do I indicate a letter in writing?

Tags: american-english

How do I write the following:
The dot above the letter I is to indicate a falafel, a common Middle Eastern food.

- do I write "letter i" or "letter I"

Comment: The English letter *l* (el or ell) doesn't have a dot above it. The letter *i* (i, ie)  does.

Comment: You should italicise a letter when you are referring to it as a letter.  In this case, you should italicise the lowercase *i* without the qualifying use of the word *letter*.

Comment: This is a matter of style; adhere to the guidance of your editor, organization, or preferred [style manual](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579).

Comment: The odd claim that the dot somehow represents "a falafel" makes me wonder if you are referring to Turkish orthography, which distinguishes between dotted and un-dotted versions of the letter *I* in both upper and lower cases: *İ/i* vs. *I/ı.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's entirely personal choice of the author. I'm not familiar with a standardised way to "quote" letters individually. One would assume that some would choose to display it like this: "i". Considering your specific example refers to the *tittle* (dot above the "i"), I'd suggest that the way that I have chosen to display it is appropriate. However, *i*, in which the letter is displayed in italics, is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was wondering, I am creating a brand book for a middle eastern restaurant, and the logo has an i with a green dot that symbolizes the falafel, that was a sentence from the book, maybe I should have clarified that but I didn't think it was necessary for an answer.

Comment: No, I don't think anything else was needed, but it's always useful to cast some context! Happy to help, sorry the answer was a dead-end.